# Search Data from a Specific Column where data to pick from is sorted by Duplicates in a Specific Column

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table that has a Column naming Title, Author, Publisher, and Type. In Column Type I specify there whether the item was a Book, Thesis, or a Magazine. So to sort them by Type I query

```
"SELECT ID, Title, Author, Publisher, Type FROM tblbooks WHERE Type = "Books""
```

this Query displays all the items that is a Book. Now I want to search from the data that has a book on their type but also on a specified Column. For example, I want to find "The Big Bad wolf" on the Column Title where the typ is Book. I tried

```
SELECT * FROM tblbooks WHERE Type="Books" LIKE '%The Big Bad Wolf%'
```

But it displays all the data in the Table Instead. How do I query this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AND` to join two conditions

```
SELECT * FROM tblbooks WHERE Type="Books" AND Title LIKE '%The Big Bad Wolf%'
                                       //^^^^^^^^^^ This was missing
```

Explanation :

> Select all columns from `tblbooks` where type of book is equal to
>   `Books` AND title contains `The Big Bad Wolf` in any position

Answer (score 0):

You could use `AND` operator with your existing condition to add the other condition. So the working query will be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblbooks 
WHERE Type = "Books" AND
      Title LIKE '%The Big Bad Wolf%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AND Operator to separate various conditions in WHERE Clause

```
SELECT * FROM tblbooks WHERE Type="Books" AND `Title` LIKE '%The Big Bad Wolf%'
```